# Sort List by occurrence of a word by LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

i have stored data in list like

```
 List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>();
 SearchResult sr = new SearchResult();
 sr.Description = "sample description";
 list.Add(sr);
```

suppose my data is stored in description field like

```
"JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700"
"Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"
"Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"
"Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"
"Wie man BBA reman erreicht"
"this test JCB"
"Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile"
```

now i want to query the list with my search term like **geo jcb**

if you look then the word **geo** has stored many times in the description field. so i want to sort my list in such way that the word in search term found maximum that data will come first. please help me to do so. thanks

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%2Aidf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a simple regular expression, just combine your search terms in the pattern with `|`:

```
var re = new Regex("geo|JCB",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Then count the number of matches in your description:

```
Console.WriteLine(re.Matches(description).Count); // Outputs '5' in your example
```

You could order your list by this:

```
searchResults.OrderByDescending(r => re.Matches(r).Count);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/MMAT58077

---

**Edit**: According to your new question linked in the comments (and hopefully you'll update the details of this question and let the duplicate die) you wish to order the results so that the most common result shows up earlier on in the list of results.

To do this, you could first calculate the relevant weighting of each search phrase, and use this to order the results.

Step1: Calculate the weighting by counting the total number of times each search word appears in the entire set of data:

```
var wordsToFind = "Geo JCB".Split();
// find number of times each search phrase is found
var weights = wordsToFind.Select( w => new { 
         Word = w, 
         Weight = list.Where(x => x.Description.Contains(w)).Count() 
    } );
```

For the data in this question at the moment this givves the result:

```
GEO: 3
JCB: 2
```

So you want all the `GEO` results first, followed by `JCB`. I guess a nice-to-have would be to have the first result be the one where `GEO` is mentioned most often.

Step2: Use the weightings calculated in step 1 to order the results of a search.

```
var values = list.Select(x => new { 
      SearchResult = x, 
      Words = x.Description.Split(' ')
   })
   .Select(x => new { 
       SearchResult = x.SearchResult, 
       Weight = weights.Sum(w => x.Words.Contains(w.Word) ? w.Weight : 0)
   })
   .OrderByDescending(x => x.Weight)
   .Select(x => x.SearchResult);
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/SLH38676

Comment: i post my modified question here again...please have look for my requiremnt. here url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393627/complex-sorting-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp

Comment: @Thomas - You need to update **this** question with the updated information, your new question will shortly be closed as a duplicate (It had 4 of 5 votes when I voted to close it)

Comment: thanks it works....but another sorting i want that....that GEO rows should come first which row data has the word GEO maximum time. this is my second requirement. will u please do the modification accordingly. thanks a lot.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `string.Split` and `Enumerable.OrderByDescending` with an anonymous type:

```
List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() { 
    new SearchResult(){Description="JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
    new SearchResult(){Description="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
    new SearchResult(){Description="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
    new SearchResult(){Description="Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
    new SearchResult(){Description="Wie man BBA reman erreicht"},
    new SearchResult(){Description="this test JCB"},
    new SearchResult(){Description="Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile"},
};

string[] searchTerms = new[]{"geo", "jcb"};
var results = 
    list.Select(sr => new { Searchresult = sr, Words = sr.Description.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries) })
        .OrderByDescending(x => x.Words.Count(w => searchTerms.Contains(w.ToLower())))
        .Select(x => x.Searchresult);
```

Comment: nothing works when i bind my datagrid like dataGridView2.DataSource = results.ToList(); the data comes in same order.....no change found.

Comment: @Thomas: Show what you've done. By the way, in your sample data there are 5 Searchresults with 1 matching word, no with more than 1 and two with 0 matches. Maybe that's the reason why you think that there's no difference.

Comment: my requirement was bit different that first sorting will be like those row will come first where the search term found maximum time. as a result GEO the word which found 3 times in 5 rows. JCB found two times in the rows. so all rows start with GEO come first then next JCB. again next sorting will be like that rows will come first where GEO found maximum time. here GEO & JCB found only once in sample. please change ur code according to my requirement if possible. thanks

Comment: i post my modified question here again...please have look for my requiremnt. here url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393627/complex-sorting-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp

Comment: What when a row has two GEO and two JCB, should it be in the first or second group, so on 2nd or 4th position (in your [sample data](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393627/complex-sorting-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp))? Side-note: I would edit your question so that it contains all informations of your second question.

Comment: a same row can not have GEO & JCB both the word. one row can have multiple JCB or GEO.

Answer (score 1):

```
List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() 
{ 
   new SearchResult { Description = "JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700" },
   new SearchResult { Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899" },
   new SearchResult { Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899" },
   new SearchResult { Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899" },
   new SearchResult { Description = "Wie man BBA reman erreicht" },
   new SearchResult { Description = "this test JCB" },
   new SearchResult { Description = "Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile" }            
   };

   var wordsToFind = "Geo JCB".Split();
   var values = list.Select(x => new { SearchResult = x, Count = x.Description.Split(' ')
                                             .Where(c => wordsToFind .Contains(c)).Count() })
                    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Count)
                    .Select(x => x.SearchResult);
```

Comment: this line giving error Count =  x.Split(' ') error msg is "WindowsFormsApplication1.SearchResult does not contain a definition for 'Split' and no extension method 'Split' accepting a first argument of type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.SearchResult' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly"

Comment: nothing works when i bind my datagrid like dataGridView2.DataSource = values.ToList(); the data comes in same order.....no change found.

Comment: @Asif: `OrderByDesending` => `OrderByDescending`

Comment: OrderByDescending is not the case when i run ur code then data comes in same order as i posted here. my requirement was bit different that first sorting will be like those row will come first where the search term found maximum time. as a result GEO the word which found 3 times in 5 rows. JCB found two times in the rows. so all rows start with GEO come first then next JCB. again next sorting will be like that rows will come first where GEO found maximum time. here GEO & JCB found only once in sample. please change ur code according to my requirement if possible. thanks

Comment: i post my modified question here again...please have look for my requiremnt. here url http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11393627/complex-sorting-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp

Answer (score 0):

```
var results = db.Blogs.AsEnumerable()
    .Select(sr => new
    {
        Searchresult = sr,
        Words = Regex.Split(sr.Name, @"[^\S\r\n {1,}").Union(Regex.Split(sr.Name2, @"[^\S\r\n]{1,}"))
    })
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.Words.Count(w => {
        foreach (var item in searchTerms)
        {
            if(w.ToLower().Contains(item))
            {
                return true;
            }
        }
        return false;
    }))
    .Select(x => x.Searchresult);
```