# Complex Sorting List by occurrence of a word by LINQ C#

Tags: c#, linq

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Sort List by occurrence of a word by LINQ C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11392014/sort-list-by-occurrence-of-a-word-by-linq-c-sharp)

I posted a similar question here, and got an answer which does not work. Here is the data that I need to sort.

```
  ID     Title
  ---    ------
  1      JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
  2      Geo Prism 1995 Geo cart Geo001 -Geo ABS #16213899
  3      Geo Prism 1995 - Geo ABS #16213899
  4      Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
  5      Wie man BBA reman erreicht
  6      this JCB test JCB
  7      Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile
```

My search data is like "JCB GEO". I want to sort it in such a way that the data will become like

```
  ID     Title
  ---    ------
  2      Geo Prism 1995 Geo cart Geo001 -Geo ABS #16213899
  3      Geo Prism 1995 - Geo ABS #16213899
  4      Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
  6      this JCB test JCB
  1      JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
  5      Wie man BBA reman erreicht
  7      Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper Teile
```

The rows that will come first are those where the data has the maximum time. So for **GEO** the word has the maximum time in most of the rows. ID 2 has the maximum time, the word GEO,  and the next row has 2 Geo word...

I said I posted this question and got the answer below, which does not work.

```
List<SearchResult> list = new List<SearchResult>() {
  new SearchResult { Description = "JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700" },
  new SearchResult { Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899" },
  new SearchResult { Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899" },
  new SearchResult { Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899" },
  new SearchResult { Description = "Wie man BBA reman erreicht" },
  new SearchResult { Description = "this test JCB" },
  new SearchResult { Description = "Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile"   }            
};
var wordsToFind = "Geo JCB".Split();
var values = list.Select(x => new { SearchResult = x, Count = x.Description.Split(' ')
  .Where(c => wordsToFind .Contains(c)).Count() })
  .OrderByDesending(x => x.Count)
  .Select(x => x.SearchResult);
```

Comment: If you got an answer that does not work, unaccept that answer and talk to the people that are active in your question in order to get a working answer. Polluting the site with multiple identical questions is not the way to go.

Comment: [See my updated answer to your original question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11392150/219661)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can do it this way?
main console program i used to test

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var list = SearchResult.GetResult();
            var wordArray = "Geo,JCB".Split(new char[] { ',' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
            list.Sort((a, b) => {
                int sum1 = 0, sum2=0;
                foreach (var item in wordArray)
                {
                    sum1 += Regex.Matches(a.Description, item).Count;
                    sum2 += Regex.Matches(b.Description, item).Count;
                }

                if (sum1 < sum2) return 1;
                else if (sum1 > sum2) return -1;
                else return 0;
            });
            foreach (var item in list)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(item.Description);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
```

the searchresult class

```
public class SearchResult
    {
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public static List<SearchResult> GetResult()
        {
            var list = new List<SearchResult>()
            {
                new SearchResult(){Description = "JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700"},
                new SearchResult(){Description = "Geo Prism 1995 Geo cart Geo001 -Geo ABS #16213899"},
                new SearchResult(){Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - Geo ABS #16213899"},
                new SearchResult(){Description = "Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899"},
                new SearchResult(){Description = "Wie man BBA reman erreicht"},
                new SearchResult(){Description = "this JCB test JCB"},
                new SearchResult(){Description = "Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile"}
            };
            return list;
        }
    }
```

returning properoutput for what u asked...
which is

```
Geo Prism 1995 Geo cart Geo001 -Geo ABS #16213899
Geo Prism 1995 - Geo ABS #16213899
this JCB test JCB
Geo Prism 1995 - ABS #16213899
JCB Excavator - ECU P/N: 728/35700
Ersatz Airbags, Gurtstrammer und Auto Körper  Teile
Wie man BBA reman erreicht
```

Comment: sorry many syntax error comes. please paste the code in ur VS2010 IDE and run it....then u can see lots of compilation error. please have look and get back to me with error free code as a result i can test it just to see whether ur code can return result set according to my requirement or not. thanks

Comment: sry.. i have a habit of directly typing the code here therefore leaving so many syntactical errors.. ill just edit my ans

Comment: still same error is there. if possible please copy ur code in VS2010 IDE and try to compile then u can see lot of error. thanks

Comment: i have edited my ans.. no syntactical errors now :)

Comment: i want to show those rows first which has search word maximum time. GEO found in most of the rows so those rows should come first which has relation with word GEO and then those rows with JCB. i hope u need to modify code a bit. thanks

Comment: this line can not be hard coded like list.Sort((a, b) => {
because when user search then he can input like GEO or GEO JCB or GEO JCB AUDI etc.